# How to get the smallest numbered element in php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Using `print_r` returns the following array:

```
Array ( [5358] => red [1] => green [503] => blue )
```

How can I access the smallest numbered element in the array, in this case "green"?

The values will change but I just need the smallest valued element.

Using `echo min($myArray);` will return "red". There must be something I'm missing here. Using `usort` or other "advanced" ways to first sort and then extract the largest value can't be the only solution here... right!?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`min()` looks in values, not in keys. [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will do the trick

```
echo min(array_keys($myArray));
```

will do the trick. To get its value, try

```
echo $myArray[min(array_keys($myArray))];
```

Comment: Ah... What a great solution! Thanks a bunch! knew there was a easy "hack" for this problem!

Comment: @Matte It's not a hack, just processing arrays.

Comment: I know... therefore the "". As a novice in PHP everything still seems like a hack to me :P

Answer (score 2):

```
min(array_keys($myArray));
```

Simple, effective

Comment: The OP wants the value of the lowest key, not the lowest key itself.

Comment: @EvanMulawski getting the from the value is such a small step past this .. can the OP really not figure that out on their own?

Comment: Your answer, without explanation, did not give the OP what he needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$min = $myArray[min(array_keys($myArray))];
```

Comment: @Evan I do not think so. My answer has the same solution

Comment: @Martin You added to yours and you have a spelling error in the second code snippet.

Comment: @Evan yeah, I admit it, but even before I've seen his answer

Comment: @Martin. So, at the time I posted the comment, this was the only correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution, same as Martin below though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sort it first.  When you provide a key - which you have done, it doesnt matter if its numeric or a string it wont be sorted.

You either need to sort it or go through the array yourself.